# Clicking on 'Manage Offline Files' does nothing in the Sync Center

Tags: windows-10, sync-center

Windows 10 Pro Edition, and when I open up Sync Center and click 'Manage Offline Files' in the left-hand sidebar nothing happens. No windows pop up, nothing shows up.

I've tried enabling folders to "allow for offline access". The pictures online in tutorials show that all you need to do is right click a folder and toggle the 'allow for offline access' option, but I don't see that toggle anywhere in the context menu, nor do I see the words 'allow for offline access' or anything of the sort.

I'm not sure what's going on here. I have another Windows 10 machine that is able to access the Sync Center and manage offline files.  That machine is a regular Windows 10 installation, with the user having elevated admin privileges. I'm on a Windows 10 pro installation, with also the same elevated admin privileges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if you have the Windows 10 Home by clicking on **start** then click on **setting**. Select **System**. Then select **About** down at the bottom left. There it will show if the Windows 10 Home is installed or the Windows 10 Pro.

If you have the Windows 10 Home, then you will not have access to the offline file managing just like the Windows 7 Home does not have access to this feature.